# Java Stuttery/Flickery/Laggy Animation In Game

Tags: java, swing, rendering, graphics2d, bufferstrategy

To be honest, I'm not to sure how to describe my problem, you can see it [here](https://i.imgur.com/M2ZWKqf.mp4). In that video of my code running, it is most prominent in the first few seconds.

Occasionally and randomly I am getting a weird flickery/stuttery/laggy glitch in my moving pipe across the screen, I've been trying to sort it out for 3 days now and I truly have no idea why it is occurring.. I have tested my code on other computers and the same happens! As this has been happening I have remained at 60fps.

Does anyone know why this would be occurring...?

My code: *(I know this code is bad, its a rushed example)*
It will probably take a few tries to experience the same bug that I am facing......

```java
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static int width = 300 - 80;
    private static int height = 168;
    private static int scale = 3;
    public static String title = "Test";

    private Thread thread;
    private JFrame frame;
    private boolean running = false;

    private BufferedImage image;

    public Test() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale));
        frame = new JFrame();
        image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    }

    public static int getWindowWidth() {
        return width * scale;
    }

    public static int getWindowHeight() {
        return height * scale;
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final double ns = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;
        double delta = 0;
        int frames = 0;
        int updates = 0;
        requestFocus();
        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while (delta >= 1) {
                update();
                updates++;
                delta--;
                render();
                frames++;
            }

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println(updates + " tps, " + frames + " fps");
                updates = 0;
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }
    
    int x = width;
    
    static BufferedImage img;
    
    static {
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(Test.class.getResource("/pipe.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void update() {
        if (x + 30 <= -1) x = width;
        else x-=2;
    }
    
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2)
    {
        g2.setColor(Color.red);
        g2.drawImage(img, x, 10, 30, 90, null);
    }

    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        
        drawToImage();
        
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(new Color(0xff00ff));
        g.fillRect(0,  0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width * scale, height * scale, null);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }
    
    public void drawToImage()
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        g2.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        draw(g2);
        g2.dispose();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test game = new Test();
        game.frame.setResizable(false);
        game.frame.setTitle(Test.title);
        game.frame.add(game);
        game.frame.pack();
        game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        game.frame.setVisible(true);

        game.start();
    }

}
```

EDIT: Paint component code that produces same result:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
    private int WIDTH = 200 * 4;
    private int HEIGHT = 150 * 4;

    int playerX = 30;
    int playerY = 30;

    Thread gameThread;

    public GamePanel()
    {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
    }

    public void startGameThread()
    {
        this.gameThread = new Thread(this);
        this.gameThread.start();
    }

    public void update()
    {
        this.playerX+= 5;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fillRect(playerX, playerY, 32, 32);

        g2.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        double drawInterval = 1000000000/60;
        double delta = 0;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long currentTime;
        long timer = 0;
        int drawCount = 0;

        while (gameThread != null)
        {
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();

            delta += (currentTime - lastTime) / drawInterval;
            timer += (currentTime - lastTime);
            lastTime = currentTime;

            if (delta >= 1)
            {
                update();
                repaint();
                drawCount++;
                delta--;
            }

            if (timer >= 1000000000)
            {
                System.out.println("FPS: " + drawCount);
                drawCount = 0;
                timer = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setTitle("Test");

        GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        window.add(gamePanel);

        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);

        gamePanel.startGameThread();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

Comment: That doesn't help me, I have already tried this with paint component and it    still gives me the same result, also there is nothing in the troubleshooting area that helps me in that article.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see a drawing `JPanel` or a Swing `Timer` in your code.  Put something together using correct principles and you might get more help.

Comment: this looks like you are updating a component off the EDT - do you? That would be a _no-no-never_ which might lead to all types of unexpected/undeterministic behaviors

Comment: I have just tried to use `SwingUtils#envokeLater` so that I can run my rendering code on the EDT, and it made no difference...

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I have posted some refactored code that used "drawing JPanel" and still produces the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

I rearranged your code.  The motion seems pretty smooth to me when I run the modified code.

When I create a Swing GUI, I use the [model-view-controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.  This pattern allows me to separate my concerns and focus on one part of the application at a time.

I created an application model using a plain Java getter/setter class to hold the player position and the size of the playing field.

All Swing applications **must start** with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that all Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Your biggest mistake was disposing of the `Graphics` instance in your `paintComponent` method.  Never dispose of a `Graphics` instance unless you create it.

I used a Swing `Timer` rather than your complicated timing code.  Pick a frame rate and stick with it.  Most monitors can't refresh any faster than 60 frames per second.

I modified your update code so the player rectangle moves back and forth.

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the additional classes inner classes so I could post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ExampleGame implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ExampleGame());
    }

    private final GameModel model;

    private final GamePanel gamePanel;

    public ExampleGame() {
        this.model = new GameModel();
        this.gamePanel = new GamePanel(model);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setTitle("Test");

        window.add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        window.pack();
        window.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        window.setVisible(true);

        Timer timer = new Timer(20, new PlayerListener(this, model));
        timer.start();
    }

    public void repaint() {
        gamePanel.repaint();
    }

    public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private final GameModel model;

        public GamePanel(GameModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            setPreferredSize(model.getPlayingField());
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            Point point = model.getPlayerePosition();
            g2.fillRect(point.x, point.y, 32, 32);
        }

    }

    public class PlayerListener implements ActionListener {

        private int increment;

        private final ExampleGame view;

        private final GameModel model;

        public PlayerListener(ExampleGame view, GameModel model) {
            this.view = view;
            this.model = model;
            this.increment = 5;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            update();
            view.repaint();
        }

        public void update() {
            Dimension d = model.getPlayingField();
            Point point = model.getPlayerePosition();
            point.x += increment;
            if (point.x > (d.width - 64)) {
                increment = -5;
                point.x += increment;
            }
            if (point.x < 32) {
                increment = 5;
                point.x += increment;
            }

            model.setPlayerePosition(point);
        }

    }

    public class GameModel {

        private final Dimension playingField;

        private Point playerePosition;

        public GameModel() {
            this.playingField = new Dimension(800, 600);
            this.playerePosition = new Point(32, 32);
        }

        public Point getPlayerePosition() {
            return playerePosition;
        }

        public void setPlayerePosition(Point playerePosition) {
            this.playerePosition = playerePosition;
        }

        public Dimension getPlayingField() {
            return playingField;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I still get a flickery outcome with a copy and paste of this.